# Converting XmlNode Text to Integer

Tags: xml, vbscript, xml-parsing

The code that I am trying to use is this.

```
Dim oNode
Set oNode = XmlDoc.SelectSingleNode("/Record/CelloXml/Integration/Case/Hearing/Court/NodeID")

Dim iIndex 
Set iIndex = (CInt((oNode.Text).substring(0,1))) - 1
```

I want to use the `iIndex` to decide the element in an arraylist to return to the parent application.

The error that I am getting currently is that I need a text object inside the `oNode.Text`

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

VBScript strings do not have a `.substring` method (or any method for that matter, they are not objects) .

If you want the 1st character as a number - 1:

```
Dim iIndex 
iIndex = clng(left(oNode.Text, 1)) - 1
```

`Set` is for object references so is not applicable here.